# Ruby Thread & Mutex : why does my code failed to fetch JSON in sequence?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mutex

I wrote a crawler which uses 8 threads to download JSON from the Internet:

```
#encoding: utf-8
require 'net/http'
require 'sqlite3'
require 'zlib'
require 'json'
require 'thread'

$mutex = Mutex.new # Lock of database and $cnt
$cntMutex = Mutex.new # Lock of $threadCnt
$threadCnt = 0 # number of running threads 
$cnt = 0 # number of lines in this COMMIT to database

db = SQLite3::Database.new "price.db"
db.results_as_hash = true
STDOUT.sync = true
start = 10000000    
def fetch(http, url, timeout = 10) 
    # ...
end

def parsePrice( i, db)
        ss = fetch(Net::HTTP.start('p.3.cn',80), 'http://p.3.cn/prices/get?skuid=J_'+i.to_s)
        doc = JSON.parse(ss)[0]
        puts "processing "+i.to_s
        STDOUT.flush
        begin
                $mutex.synchronize {
                        $cnt = $cnt+1
                        db.execute("insert into prices (id, price) VALUES (?,?)", [i,doc["p"].to_f])
                        if $cnt > 20
                                db.execute('COMMIT')
                                db.execute('BEGIN')
                                $cnt = 0
                        end
                }
        rescue SQLite3::ConstraintException
                warn("duplicate id: "+i.to_s)
                $cntMutex.synchronize {
                        $threadCnt -= 1;
                }
                Thread.terminate
        rescue NoMethodError
                warn("Matching failed")
        rescue
                raise
        ensure
        end

        $cntMutex.synchronize {
                $threadCnt -= 1;
        }
end



puts "will now start from " + start.to_s()
db.execute("BEGIN")

Thread.new {
        for ii in start..12000000 do

                sleep 0.1 while $threadCnt > 7

                $cntMutex.synchronize {
                        $threadCnt += 1;
                }
                Thread.new { 
                        parsePrice( ii, db)
                }



        end
        db.execute('COMMIT')
} . join
```

Then I created a database named `price.db`:

```
sqlite3 > create table prices (id INT PRIMATY KEY, price REAL);
```

To make my code thread-safe, `db`, `$cnt`, `$threadCnt` are all protected by `$mutex` or `$cntMutex`.

However, when I tried to run this script, the following messages were printed:

```
[lz@lz crawl]$ ruby priceCrawler.rb 
will now start from 10000000
http://p.3.cn/prices/get?skuid=J_10000008http://p.3.cn/prices/get?skuid=J_10000008
http://p.3.cn/prices/get?skuid=J_10000008http://p.3.cn/prices/get?skuid=J_10000002http://p.3.cn/prices/get?skuid=J_10000008
http://p.3.cn/prices/get?skuid=J_10000008



http://p.3.cn/prices/get?skuid=J_10000002http://p.3.cn/prices/get?skuid=J_10000002

processing 10000002
processing 10000002processing 10000008processing 10000008processing 10000002

duplicate id: 10000002

duplicate id: 10000002processing 10000008
processing 10000008duplicate id: 10000008


duplicate id: 10000008processing 10000008
duplicate id: 10000008
```

It seems that this script skipped some id and called `parsePrice` with the same id more than once.

So why did this error occur? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that your thread scheduling is wrong. I have modified your code to illustrates some possible race conditions you were triggering.

```
re 'net/http'
require 'sqlite3'
require 'zlib'
require 'json'
require 'thread'

$mutex = Mutex.new # Lock of database and $cnt
$cntMutex = Mutex.new # Lock of $threadCnt
$threadCnt = 0 # number of running threads 
$cnt = 0 # number of lines in this COMMIT to database

db = SQLite3::Database.new "price.db"
db.results_as_hash = true
STDOUT.sync = true
start = 10000000    
def fetch(http, url, timeout = 10) 
  # ...
end

def parsePrice(i, db)
  must_terminate = false

  ss = fetch(Net::HTTP.start('p.3.cn',80), "http://p.3.cn/prices/get?skuid=J_#{i}")
  doc = JSON.parse(ss)[0]
  puts "processing #{i}"
  STDOUT.flush
  begin
    $mutex.synchronize {
      $cnt = $cnt+1
      db.execute("insert into prices (id, price) VALUES (?,?)", [i,doc["p"].to_f])
      if $cnt > 20
        db.execute('COMMIT')
        db.execute('BEGIN')
        $cnt = 0
      end
    }
  rescue SQLite3::ConstraintException
    warn("duplicate id: #{i}")
    must_terminate = true
  rescue NoMethodError
    warn("Matching failed")
  rescue
    # Raising here does not prevent ensure from running.
    # It will raise after we decrement $threadCnt on
    # ensure clause.
    raise
  ensure
    $cntMutex.synchronize {
      $threadCnt -= 1;
    }
  end

  Thread.terminate if must_terminate
end

puts "will now start from #{start}"

# This begin makes no sense for me.
db.execute("BEGIN")

for ii in start..12000000 do
  should_redo = false

  # Instead of sleeping, we acquire the lock and check
  # if we can create another thread. If we can't, we just 
  # release the lock and retry latter (using for-redo).
  $cntMutex.synchronize{
    if $threadCnt <= 7
      $threadCnt += 1;
      Thread.new { parsePrice(ii, db) }
    else
      # We use this flag since we don't know for sure redo's
      # behavior inside a lock.
      should_redo = true
    end

  }

  # Will redo this iteration if we can't create the thread.
  if should_redo
    # Mitigate busy waiting a bit.
    sleep(0.1)
    redo
  end
end

# This commit makes no sense to me.
db.execute('COMMIT')

Thread.list.each { |t| t.join }
```

Also, most databases already implement locks themselves. You can probably remove the mutex that locks the database. And another advice is that you be more consistent with your commits. You have a lot of scattered begins and commits in the code. I suggest that you either make the operation and then commit or use a commit buffer and then commit everything in a single place.

The race condition, it seems you were not being careful enough when dealing with `$threadCnt`. The implementation I gave you makes more sense to me, but I have not tested it.

The `redo` in the main loop is a form of busy waiting, which is bad for performance. You can and you should put a sleep clause there. But it is essential that you maintain the `$threadCnt` checking and updating inside the lock. The way you implemented it before did not ensure the check and updating was an atomic operation.